# Get the precision of a float in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I wanted to get to get the precision of a decimal number for my application, 
I tried several methods but I couldn't get what i wanted.

At starter i tried to convert the float to a string, and do a simple split on it and stock that in a list of ints, then gets the length of the list

```
let a = 12.12345678910111213141516;;
let stringA = string_of_float a;;

let list_of_ints stringA = List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp "\.") stringA);;
let stringList = list_of_ints stringA;;
let thedecimal = string_of_int (List.nth stringList 1);;

S.length thedecimal;;
```

the problem is whenever i have more than 10 numbers in the characteristic side of my float it doesn't work, it always return 10

```
val a : float = 12.1234567891011125
val stringA : string = "12.1234567891"
val list_of_ints : string -> int list = <fun>
val stringList : int list = [12; 1234567891]
val thedecimal : string = "1234567891"
- : int = 10
```

my second method was trying to do a subtraction between the float number and 
it's characteristic, so that i get the mantissa, then stock it on a list and 
get the length of it minus 2 (0 and the .)

```
let b = int_of_float a;;
let c = a -. (float_of_int b);;
S.length (string_of_float c)-2;;
```

It returns 12, which is weird cause I'm expecting a 23,

```
val b : int = 12
val c : float = 0.123456789101112463
- : int = 12
```

I'm new with Ocaml. If anyone have any solution to how get the precision, I need your help, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `string_of_float` decided to limit the number of displayed significant digits to twelve (I'd have to look into it to be sure).

This is actually a good thing, because a double could be represented as a pretty big number.

```
# let f = 0.123456789012345678901234567890;;   
val f : float = 0.123456789012345677
# let s = string_of_float f;;
val s : string = "0.123456789012"
# let s' = Printf.sprintf "%.10f" f;;
val s' : string = "0.1234567890"
# let s'' = Printf.sprintf "%.30f" f;;
val s'' : string = "0.123456789012345677369886232100"
# let s''' = Printf.sprintf "%.60f" f;;
val s''' : string =
  "0.123456789012345677369886232099815970286726951599121093750000"
(* longer than this one just add zeroes *)
```

Now, you're asking for a number actual precision. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> - Sign bit: 1 bit
> - Exponent: 11 bits
> - Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

And furthermore...

> The format is written with the significand having an implicit integer
>   bit of value 1 (except for special data, see the exponent encoding
>   below). With the 52 bits of the fraction significand appearing in the
>   memory format, the total precision is therefore 53 bits (approximately
>   16 decimal digits, 53 log10(2) ≈ 15.955).
>
> Between 252=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 253=9,007,199,254,740,992 the
>   representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range,
>   from 253 to 254, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable
>   numbers are the even ones, etc. Conversely, for the previous range
>   from 251 to 252, the spacing is 0.5, etc.
>
> The spacing as a fraction of the numbers in the range from 2n to 2n+1
>   is 2n−52. The maximum relative rounding error when rounding a number
>   to the nearest representable one (the machine epsilon) is therefore
>   2−53.

So you have it, your precision is around `2^-53` with respect to your float's value. This gives you around **15 or 16 decimal digits of precision** for any float.

As a side note, if you're using regexps on a float, you need to calm down and think about kittens for a minute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... and allow me to ask, I didn't quite understand what you meant at the end with the **kittens** when using `regexps` ?

Comment: That was a humorous attempt. Every time you use regexps on floats, a kitten dies. Think about the kittens.

Comment: Oh, okey :) kittens life matter !

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limited number of bits in the representation of doubles, the maximal precision is 324. See [Wikipedia](http://By%20compromising%20precision,%20the%20subnormal%20representation%20allows%20even%20smaller%20values%20up%20to%20about%205%20%C3%97%2010%E2%88%92324.).

> By compromising precision, the subnormal representation allows even smaller values up to about 5 × 10−324.

The following function is what you want.

```
let precision_of_float f = 
  let (fractional, _) = modf f in
  let fractional_string = (Printf.sprintf "%.324f" fractional) in 

  (* remove ending zeros *)
  let fractional_string = Str.replace_first (Str.regexp "0+$") "" fractional_string in

  (* fractional_string is of the form 0.[0-9]* *)
  String.length fractional_string - 2
```